# Malfacilaĵoj pri tradukado el la angla esperanten

Tags: translation, accusative, literature

Mi provas traduki la ĉi-suban frazon esperanten:

"Far below she could see an arm of the lake—no longer green, but dimmed by distance to a misted blue."

Mia unua provo:

"Malsupre, tre malproksime, ŝi povis vidi brakon de la lago - ne plu verdan sed paligitan pro la distanco al nebuleta bluo."

Du punktoj estas malklaraj:

1. Ĉu "malsupre, tre malproksime" estas la plej bona traduko de "far below"?
2. Ĉu mia uzado de la akuzitivan ĉe "verdan" kaj "paligitan" pravas? Aldone, ĉu la manko de akuzativo ĉe "nebuleta bluo" estas senerara?

(La fonta teksto estas el la malnova romano "The Wheel Spins" verkita Ethel Lina White, kiun Hitchcock uzis por krei la filmon "The Lady Vanishes".)

Antaŭdankon pro ia helpo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respondo de Eduardo estas pli bona, jen tamen kelkaj rimarkigoj.

> "Malsupre, tre malproksime, ŝi povis vidi brakon de la lago - ne plu verdan sed paligitan pro la distanco al nebuleta bluo."

Tre bona, gramatike bona traduko:

- la brako estis verda, ne la lago.

Nur la kombino de du mal-formoj ne estas bela, flua, tro haltiga. Do erareta *malproksime sube* estus en ordo miaopinie.
La uzo de *fore* ankaŭ plaĉas al mi.

> "Tute/Longe malsupre, ŝi povis vidi lagobrakon/lagobranĉon - ne plu verdan sed paligitan pro la distanco al nebula/vuala bluo."

*nebul**et**a* celas probable eviti laŭliterecan interpreton. Tiam uzu *vuala*.

*lagobrakon* estas pli rekta.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani. Bela angla rimedo. Mi serĉis pli mallongan formuladon kia _far below_, kaj mia argumentado tie estas subjektiva.

Answer (score 2):

> Ĉu "malsupre, tre malproksime" estas la plej bona traduko de "far below"?

Estas klara kaj komprenebla. `Tre for` ankaŭ funkcius. Ĉu iu estas plej bona? Ne vere eblas respondi tion. Ekzemple, vi *povus* enkonduki la malsupron per "la valo"; `tre for en la valo`. Tio apartenas pli al arta kampo ol al gramatika aŭ lingva. Via traduko bonas.

> ŝi povis vidi brakon de la lago - ne plu verdan sed paligitan pro la distanco al nebuleta bluo.

Parton de via demando respondas ["Perverba priskribo de objekto"](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/specialaj_priskriboj/perverba/objekto.html) en PMEG. Oni vidas tie la malsamon inter "farbi la domon ruĝan", "farbi la domon ruĝa" kaj "farbi la ruĝan domon verda".

Ĉar ŝajne temas ĉiam pri ŝia percepto, kaj kiam la afero videblis verda kaj kiam ĝi iĝis nebulete blua vi povus skribi:

- *ne plu verda sed paligita pro la distanco al nebuleta bluo.* (farbi la domon ruĝa).

Sed eble vi volas aldoni informon, ke la brako estas ja fakte verda. Vi do povus skribi:

- *ŝi povis vidi verdan brakon de la lago paligita pro la distanco al nebuleta bluo.* (farbi la ruĝan domon verda)

En via unua provo de traduko la dua parto estas rekta priskribo de la objekto "brako" kaj do vi diras nenion pri *kiel* oni vidas la brakon, sed pri tio, ke oni ĝin vidas, kaj kia ĝi estas.

- *ŝi povis vidi brakon de la lago - ne plu verdan sed paligitan pro la distanco al nebuleta bluo.* (farbi la ruĝan domon)